# perl check for valid DNA sequence with regex

Tags: regex, perl, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, bioperl

I want to write a subroutine that takes a FASTA file as an argument and prints out the sequence (without the header). 
The subroutine should check if the sequence contains any other letters than DNA bases (A, T, G, C).

Here's my code:

```
scalar_sequence ("sequence.fa");

sub scalar_sequence {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my $sequence;
    open (READ, $file) || die "Cannot open $file: $!.\n";
    while (<READ>){
        if (/^>/){
            next;
        } 
        if (/^[ATCG]/){
            $sequence .= $_;
        } else {
            die "invalid sequence\n";
        }
    }
    print $sequence, "\n";
}
```

When I run this code, I get 'invalid sequence' as output.
When I leave the 'else' out, it prints out the sequence even when the sequence contains another letter.

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `^` should be in `[]` : `if (/[^ATCG]/)`

Comment: okay, now it prints the sequence instead of the error message, BUT: it prints the sequence even when it includes invalid letters

Comment: also not working :/

Comment: Be advised: bioperl's `seqIO` is ~10x faster than reading fasta files in native perl.  If you're dealing with higher organisms (large genome), this can be a substantial boon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `/^[ATCG]/` this line should be `/^[ATCG]+$/`

Your code should be

```
chomp;  
next if (/^>/); # skip for header
next if(/^\s*$/);  #skip for empty line
if (/^[ATCG]+$/){
        $sequence .= $_;
    } else {
        die "invalid sequence\n";
    }
```

You are only consider the beginning of the line start wit A or T or G or C. You should expand the matches.

Comment: doesn't work either, prints out 'invalid sequence' even when sequence is valid

Comment: @ic23oluk Because of new line. Add  `chomp` in your script.

Comment: @ic23oluk In every fasta file last line is a new line. Please remove die from your `else` condition. And print the `$sequence`.

Comment: that's not exactly what i want: If i leave out 'die' it prints the sequence even when it harbors invalid letters, but without the lines in which these invalid letters are.
I want to write an algorithm that stops when one or more invalid letters are included and return an error message

Comment: When removing the last newline in the fasta file it works as desired, but how can I do this automatically?